# Insert new text in the middle of a file replacing old text without re-inserting the same things over and over?

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression, perl

I have a file that I want to update relatively frequently.
What needs to be done is that a specific part of the file would be changed to include some more lines. I am doing it with `sed` and `\a` option:
So this works:

```
sed -i "/import:/a\$IMPORTED" file
```

This works as expected the first time. On the next re-runs this commands appends over and over the same lines.
How would I approach this so that I somehow remove everything I imported before I run it again?
E.g. use some following lines to anchor in the beginning that I know were not added automatically or something like that?

Comment: How do you know when the old $IMPORTED ends?

Comment: @JeffSchaller:I know the format of the lines I add. And also I could consider the following line as an anchor but that would be error prone in case it changed

Comment: @don_crissti: I don't know that except that I kind of know the format of what I insert

Comment: @don_crissti: The added lines have a specific prefix: e.g. `foo/bar/etc`. But I am not sure if there won't be any other addition that wasn't done by `sed`.

Comment: @don_crissti: I was thinking to add some comment in the end of the line but then if I do: `sed -i "s/^.*\/\/comment here//g" file` it inserts space so I get empty lines

Comment: @don_crissti: E.g. Let's say I add 10 lines the first time and have at the end `// auto-lines`. If I insert 2 lines the next time then using the comment as a marker and `sed -i "s/^.*\/\/comment here//g" file` I get my 2 new lines and 8 empty lines

Comment: `sed` can `d`elete lines, no problem. So if you know those comments are always only on inserted lines, delete those lines e.g. `\|// auto-lines|d`

Answer (score 0):

Your command:

```
sed "/import:/a\$IMPORTED" infile
```

Is inserting the literal `$IMPORTED` text on linux and GNU sed. The problem is that the shell is interpreting the backslash before the `$`. You can either quote correctly:

```
sed '/import:/a\'"$IMPORTED" infile
```

Or, split the value in its own script part:

```
sed -e '/import:/a\' -e "$IMPORTED" infile
```

It is always better to single quote sed scripts.

To **replace** an `old` value with a `new` one that may contain an undefined number of lines, you need to

- First: capture all lines in the pattern space:

  sed 'H;1h;$!d;x' infile
- Set values to change:

  old='original'
  new='newvalue'
- Remove old value (which must exist):

  sed -E -e 'H;1h;$!d;x' -e 's/(import:)(\n)'"$old"'/\1/g' infile
- Add the new input:

  sed -E -e 'H;1h;$!d;x' -e 's/(import:)(\n)'"$old"'/\1/g' -e 's/(import:)/\1\n'"$new"'/g' infile

There is an corner issue in that if the variable `$old` contains a null value (empty) a newline will gets removed. To solve that we need:

```
sed -E -e 'H;1h;$!d;x' -e 's/(import:)'"${old:+"(\\n)$old"}"'/\1/g' -e 's/(import:)/\1\n'"$new"'/g' infile
```

Comment: 1) I need to add remove the existing importing and add/refresh the new ones 2) Why is single quoting better? 3) I don't really understand the snippet. Could you please elaborate what's happening there?

Comment: (1)and(3) I'll try. (2) Because it avoids the interpretation of backslash (and other characters like `$`, `!`, etc.) by the shell which change what sed receives as commands.